# using linq to orderBy in list of lists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-core

I have the following model:

```
public class Person {
    public int Id {get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set; }
    public List <Car> Cars {get; set; }
}

public class Car {
    public int Id {get; set; }
    public string Make {get; set; }
    public string Color {get; set; }
}

var persons = new List<Person>(){.....}
```

I want to query the persons list and order it by `Person.Name` and `Car.Make`.

I want the person list to be sorted by Person.Name, and the individual person car list to be sorted by Car.Make

```
var entities = Persons
                .Include(h => h.Cars)
                .Where(h => h.Id == 1).OrderBy(h => h.Name).ToList();
```

Order by `Person.Name` works fine, but I need to order by `Car.Make` also. 
since I can't use orderBy within `.Include(h => h.Cars),` so I decided to order it using a foreach,

```
        entities.ForEach(h =>  {
            h.Cars.OrderBy(t => t.Make); 
        });
```

this didn't work. How do I make it work?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your use case. So, you sort by Person.Name, but what is your expectation with sorting by Car.Make? Do you mean that if two persons have the same name, then they should be sorted by the cars they "own"? If you could please clarify your intended result.

Comment: I agree with Luc Morin. The intent is not clear. Are you looking to order by person name and then have the Cars list be ordered by Make for each person? Or are you looking for a cross multiplication result where you have a row for each person/car combination sorted by person name and car make?

Comment: I want the person list to be sorted by Person.Name, and the individual person car list to be sorted by Car.Make

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Regarding OrderBy()**

The [`OrderBy()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx) method returns a collection of items as opposed to ordering in-place, so you would need to set your `Cars` to that specific value:

```
entities.ForEach(h => {
     // This will order your cars for this person by Make
     h.Cars = h.Cars.OrderBy(t => t.Make).ToList(); 
});
```

You could potentially handle this within a single call with a `Select()` statement as well to avoid iterating through the list once more with a `ForEach()` call:

```
var entities = Persons.Include(h => h.Cars)
                      .Where(h => h.Id == 1)
                      .OrderBy(h => h.Name)
                      // .ToList() (Use this if calling directly from EF)
                      .Select(p => new Person(){
                          Id = p.Id,
                          Name = p.Name,
                          Cars = p.Cars.OrderBy(c => c.Name).ToList()
                      });
```

Comment: I don't think you can use `Person` entity in a LINQ projection ( if `db.Persons` is a collection of `Person` type)

Comment: It wasn't super clear in the original post (as the `this` seems a bit off), but if this is being called directly from a context, then you would likely need a `ToList()` prior to the `Select()` statement in order for this to work as expected.

Comment: This just reminded me once again why I've moved on, to `massive/petapoco/dapper`. Whew!